# Django and login "remember me": How can I view that status for other code?

Tags: django, session, django-allauth

I am using Django with the Allauth login code (and still a bit wet) to perform authentication.  It appears that if you check "remember me", it does the following in the allauth login form:

allauth forms.py (class LoginForm)

```
if remember:
        request.session.set_expiry(app_settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE)
    else:
        request.session.set_expiry(0)
    return ret
```

I am trying to use the "remember me" for other features in my app.  It **appears** that the only 'flag' I have to determine if a user wants to be remembered or not is the above value.

In my view code, I tried to read this 'flag' with the following command:

```
request.session.get_expiry_age()
```

Unfortunately, it always returns 1209600.  Whether the user checks the "remember me" box or not, this value is 1209600.

I need to find this flag so that I can use it in several places.  What system variable is set and exposed when a user checks this 'Remember me' box that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 2):

Reading [set_expiry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.set_expiry) and [get_expiry_age()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.get_expiry_age) will be helpful.

Relevant parts:

> set_expiry(value)
>
> If value is 0, the user’s session cookie will expire when the user’s Web browser is closed.

---

> get_expiry_age()
>
> Returns the number of seconds until this session expires. For sessions with no custom expiration (or those set to expire at browser close), this will equal SESSION_COOKIE_AGE.

It indicates that when we do:

```
request.session.set_expiry(0)
```

Below part:

```
request.session.get_expiry_age()
```

Will return `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`.

---

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1877ec18753947795b7821f8b9176bd7ea7c03a3/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py#L258) will help.